# Generate unique browser ID in nodejs server from http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

So I am working on a nodejs server backend and wanting to create a unique id for each browser that connects to it. I have this code here:

```js
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    //generate unique browser ID
}
server.listen(1234, "127.0.0.1");
```

So is there a way to make a unique browser ID from the `req` or `res` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

```
app.use(session({
    genid: function(req) {
        return genuuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
    },
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}))
```